# Window.Focus on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, focus

I have this simple code to call a window. 
http://jsfiddle.net/94KYp/43/

```
var myWindow = window.open('','zzz','width=600,height=700');
myWindow.focus();
```

this works fine on Chrome and Firefox ONLY on first load.
but when i try to click outside of the popup, and reRun the code, it will not set the focus back to the Popup..

When you go to my jsfiddle link and the popup is loaded, click out of the popup(don't close), then rerun the code. It should set the focus back to the popup(which doesn't).

Works on IE.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `document.write` after the document has loaded the browser will open a new document that replaces the current one.

Replace it with an `alert()` and you will observe the event being re-raised.

Comment: thanks for the response. actually, the document.write doesn't matter on my current issue. i just put it there to have something on the new window. what i want to happen is, when you go to my jsfiddle link and the popup is loaded, click out of the popup(don't close), then rerun the code. It should set the focus back to the popup. i've updated my question